# Simple plotly histogram of monthly frequencies in R

Tags: r, plotly, histogram

So I know that this is a super simple question, but still I could not resolve it. I have data that looks like this with precise dates in one year:

```
         date
1  2008-08-08
2  2008-08-08
3  2008-04-12
4        <NA>
5        <NA>
6  2008-04-10
7  2008-07-12
8  2008-04-10
9        <NA>
10 2008-07-12
11 2008-07-14
12 2008-07-29
13 2008-07-29
14 2008-07-29
15 2008-08-06
16       <NA>
17 2008-08-24
18 2008-10-30
19 2008-10-30
20 2008-10-20
21 2008-01-28
22       <NA>
23       <NA>
```

I would like to plot the frequency of the data per month. So I do something like

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(month = month(date),
         month_posix = as.Date(paste0("2008-", month, "-01"))) %>% 
  plot_ly(., x = ~month_posix)
```

But I just don't know how to plot one bin for each month with the frequency of its appearance. I tried a couple of things, but I'M just not really familiar with plotly. Like if there are zero dates in January I would still like to see January with a bar of height 0.
Maybe someone has a quick tip.

Data in the format I have (just without NAs) can be produced with this command:
`dat = data.frame(date = sample(seq(as.Date('2008-01-01'), as.Date('2008-12-31'), by="day"), 16))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `count` to get the frequency in each month and then use `plot_ly`

```
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)
library(plotly)

dat %>% 
  count(month = month(date), name = 'count') %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~month, y = ~count, type = 'bar')
```

[image]

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
dat = data.frame(date = sample(seq(as.Date('2008-01-01'), 
                                   as.Date('2008-12-31'), by="day"), 50))
```

Comment: thanks a lot!!:) But if there is for example no data for december, the plot only goes until November:/ Is there any way to specify that I want exactly one bin for each month?

Comment: @RobinKohrs I don't know how to do it in `plotly` but you can do it in `ggplot` and turn it into plotly object if needed. `dat %>% count(month = factor(month(date), 1:12), name = 'count') %>% ggplot() + aes(month, count) + geom_col() + scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)`
`

Comment: awesome! Thanks a lot:) I'll give this one a shot